# How to enhance-iterate by reference over an array element that's of type set (STL) of user-defined objects?

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, stl, constants

`necklace` is a c-array consisting of elements that are `std::set<Pearl>`, where `Pearl` is a user-defined type.

`necklace` is defined as follows

```
std::set<Pearl> necklace[NUM_CIRC] = { };
```

After this the elements are populated with the `Pearl`'s.

The following snippet

```
for (Pearl &p : necklace[circular_coordinate]) {
    p.set_color("white");
}
```

results in a compile error

> invalid initialization of reference of type 'Pearl&' from
>   expression of type 'const Pearl'

How can I access `necklace[circular_coordinate]` in a non-const fashion?

Comment: If `necklace` is an array you should be using `for (Pearl &p : necklace)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to access non-const member functions of objects in C++ std::set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10662206/unable-to-access-non-const-member-functions-of-objects-in-c-stdset)

Comment: [MCVE]: `std::set<int> s; for (int& n : s)(void) n;` -> _" error: binding reference of type 'int&' to 'const int' discards qualifiers"_

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, `std::set` elements are immutable. This means, you **can't** change them by design.

The reason for this is the same as with immutable keys in `std::set` and `std::map` - changing the key might result in changed order between keys, which is not supported by associative containers.

Comment: Thanks. Do you happen to have a suggestion for alternative containers that allow the modification of the members? I don't want to allocate a 2D array to save memory (some location have a large number of pearls and others only 1).

Comment: @WuschelbeutelKartoffelhuhn Why not a simple `vector` or `list`? You need to refine your requirements if you want more precise suggestions.

Comment: Thanks. IIRC vector allocates memory for 10 members initially (although that can probably be changed), so I'll go with list (which I assume is a LL). I don't need O(1) member access anyway.

Comment: @WuschelbeutelKartoffelhuhn `std::vector` has a constructor that takes the desired initial number of elements as a parameter. That'll be useful for your case. Also, `std::vector` is better than `std::list` in almost **all** cases when you do not require random deletion.

Comment: @WuschelbeutelKartoffelhuhn If you're not absolutly sure you need anything else than an `std::vector`, use a vector.